# ag-grid: Multiple independent headerCheckSelection Boolean columns which toggle states of entire column values?

Tags: checkbox, ag-grid

One or more ag-grid Boolean checkbox columns need to have a check(true)/uncheck(false) all capability.

The headerCheckSelection column property nicely shows a checkbox in the column header name (see below). It though is used for row selection which is not the intent.

[Three Boolean columns, two with headerCheckSelection Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sEiL.png)

Can the headerCheckSelection column property be used with other properties/functions to toggle the Boolean values of its column entries without selecting any rows?
This needs to work for multiple Boolean columns where each is independent of the others.

If not, what other options are available for having a column specific check/uncheck all capability?